# Custom pooled allocator in C++ besides boost::pool

Tags: c++, boost, stl, malloc, allocator

I've got a usage scenario in C++ where a function I'm calling many times creates a few local, small but dynamically-sized vectors.  After profiling my program, I noticed that an inordinate amount of time was being spent in std::vector::free().  A natural (C++-esque) solution to such a problem seemed to be to switch the default allocator to something more agreeable to my usage scenario.  In particular, using a memory pool strategy seemed like it would make sense here.  However, boost::pool_alloc has been nothing but trouble so far.  I've gotten it to work, but while the allocations are faster in my small but oft-called function (we'll call that function f()), it causes the function that calls f() to hang before returning for a *very long time*.

Yet more profiling shows that that all of the time (literally tens of minutes before I got tired of waiting) are being spent in pool_allocator::ordered_free().  I reproduced this same behavior (though not as extreme) in a simple test program, and it seems that, indeed, when a large set of constructed vectors return their memory to the singleton pool, the function just hangs for a very long time before returning.

If anyone knows of a way to avoid this behavior, or of another C++ pool allocator that doesn't suffer from such a problem, I'd be much obliged!

Comment: `reserve`-ing correctly can really help (if you are not already).

Comment: Hi Justin,  Yea, I'm already reserving the vectors.  The problem is that I know the size of each vector at the time of function invocation (i.e. they're not growing), but not at compile time, so they're still dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own a couple times where allocating and freeing is super fast once everything gets going. 
1. Create a map of pools by size. 
2. Each pool has a doubly linked list of blocks. 
3.each block has extra space at the front and back for the list node and owner pool reference, size checks, etc
4. Allocating is fast because you just need to look up the first pool with size >= your block size and unlist the first entry. 
5. Deallocating is fast because you have a pointer to the pool right in the memory block,  so all you have to do is relist it. 
6. You can create a bunch of empty pools on startup. Then, on each alloc, try un listing from the pool first. If that fails, then malloc() instead. When the block is freed, add it back to the pool instead of freeing it. 
7. Once your app is running stably, all allocs will come straight from the pools linked list and frees will go right back there... Super fast. 
8. When your program exits, Free() all of the memory in the pools.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that

- It's only that one function
- The size of the vectors is limited (you say it's small)
- The function is not called recursively too often

If that's the case consider to use stack-allocated memory instead of dynamically allocated memory. You can do that by either not using vector but using `std::array<>` and some size indicator (if the stored type istrivially constructible) or some raw memory buffer of fixed size and placement new, or wrap the latter into an allocator class to use vector with that allocator class.

If your performance problem is constrained to such a small region of code, I would not use such general purpose memory management tools as boost::pool but roll something very specialized for the situation at hand.

Comment: Hi Arne.  The stored type is trivially constructible (it's size_t).  However, I can't really use stack allocated storage because the scenario is a little bit more complicated than I initially let on.  In particular, while a large number of vectors are created within each function call, and most of them are destroyed before the function returns, a small number of them do get incorporated into other heap objects and escape the function.  I suppose I could just copy those vectors (rather than move).  I wanted to avoid writing my *own* allocator, but that might be the best way forward.

Comment: if you know beforehand which vectors get moved to the heap objects, you can use standard allocators for them.